# Homogeneous system of Paramters: Searching for the "smallest" affine variety on which a given set is still algebraically independent

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I have the following problem:
Let  $K$ be a algebraically closed field and $f_1,...,f_r\in K[x_1,...,x_n]=K[V]$ be algebraically independent and homogeneous.
Are there homogeneous and algebraically independent $g_{r+1},...,g_n\in K[V]$ such that $f_1,...,f_r,g_{r+1},...,g_n$ is a homogeneous system of parameters of $K[V]$, i.e. $f_1,...,f_r,g_{r+1},...,g_n$ are algebraically independent, homogeneous and $K[f_1,...,f_r,g_{r+1},...,g_n]\subseteq K[V]$ is finite (which is satisfied in this case),
and $$K[f_1,...,f_r]\cap (g_{r+1},...,g_n)_{K[V]}=\{0\},$$ the intersection of $K[f_1,...,f_r]$ with the ideal generated by $g_{r+1},...,g_n$ in $K[V]$ is zero?

Or viewing this in the geometric way:
$$\phi^*:K[V']=K[x_1,...,x_r]\to K[V],\quad x_i\mapsto f_i$$
$$\phi:V\to V',\quad v\mapsto (f_1(v),...,f_r(v))$$
Now $\phi^*$ is injective, since $f_1,...,f_r$ are algebraically independent. So $\phi$ is dominant. Now the question is: Is there an $r$-dimensional affine variety $Z={\cal{V}}(g_{r+1},...,g_n)\subseteq V$ such that
$$\phi:Z\to V'$$ is still dominant and $f_1,...,f_r,g_{r+1},...,g_n$ is a homogeneous system of parameters?

Maybe even a vectorspace $W=Z$ satisfies this, i.e. we find homogeneous linear $g_{r+1},...,g_n$. This would be equivalent as saying we are able to substitute $n-r$ variables (w.l.o.g. $x_{r+1},...,x_n$) with a linear combination of the $r$ others, such that
$$f_1(x_1,...,x_r,\sum_{i=1}^r \lambda_{(r+1,i)}x_i,...,\sum_{i=1}^r \lambda_{(n,i)}x_i),...,f_r(x_1,...,x_r,\sum_{i=1}^r \lambda_{(r+1,i)}x_i,...,\sum_{i=1}^r \lambda_{(n,i)}x_i) $$
are still algebraically independent. I only can think of examples where this can be done. This would also be the maximal "reduction of variables" possible.

Did someone come across such a problem? (books, scripts ?)